# Is there a mock program that uses the CPU on multiple cores?

Tags: profiling

I am playing around with `htop`, `gprof`, etc. I'd like a program that basically just runs on multiple cores so I can profile it and learn how to use these tools. I know I can write my own `c++` code with `-fopenmp` and run a useless loop, but I was hoping there's a stock unix command I can use?

Basically I just want a program that uses 100% of however many cores I tell it, until I ask it to stop. Does this exist?

Comment: can't you just run a single core program (e.g., `md5sum /dev/urandom`) twice or more time in parallel?

Comment: @pqnet yeah but it won't show up as a single process running on multiple threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not stock, but here are a few tool I have used before:

- primes (usually in your distributions games package) just simply fork off a few dozen and it will generate primes from now until forever.
- Stress: http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/
- CPUBurn: http://patrickmylund.com/projects/cpuburn/

Comment: Very nice. I already had `stress` installed and it worked like a charm (I used `stress -n 4` to run on 4 cores).